# how to setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt for Appirater

Tags: appirater

I've been trying to figure this out for HOURS and can't get it to work.

This is what I have in appirater.m:

```
static NSString *_appId = @"999999";
static double _daysUntilPrompt = 0;
static NSInteger _usesUntilPrompt = 1;
static NSInteger _significantEventsUntilPrompt = 10;
static double _timeBeforeReminding = 1;
```

I have a simple game and I want the appirater to come on specifically at level 10.

I would very much appreciate any help!  Thanks!

Comment: Or not specifically at level 10...but after they play 10 levels.

Answer (score 1):

First set the number:

```
[Appirater setSignificantEventsUntilPrompt:10];
```

After you call the method below, the number of significant will increment by 1, and when meet the significant event count, it will prompt the dialog.

```
[Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES]
```

significantEventsUntilPrompt: 
after how many significant events user performed (Significant events can be like - completed a level in game, achieved/unlocked some thing etc). You can tell Appirater that user has performed significant event by [Appirater userDidSignificantEvent:YES]